# Prove there is no solution of the equation

Tags: group-theory

I need to prove that there is no solution of the following equation

$$x^3\equiv 2\pmod{151}$$

I think that it has something to do with "Fermat little theorem" and/or "Euler theorem", but I can't seem to find the way to prove that.

Besides the fact that $151$ is prime, I can't find the connection between the two theorems..

Comment: Well if $2$ was a cube, then by Fermat's little theorem we would have $2^{50} \equiv 1 \mod 151$, but in fact $2^{50} \equiv 32 \mod 151$. Of course that requires a calculation!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that if $x$ is a solution then clearly $x\not\equiv 0$, so by Fermat $$2^{50}\equiv x^{150}\equiv 1\pmod{151}.$$

Comment: I know that it is probably a silly question, but why $2^{50}$ ?

Comment: @Buzi: by Fermat, $x^{150} = 1\mod 151$, and if $x^3=2\mod 151$ (the assumption), we obtain $2^{50} = 1\mod 151$.

Comment: Fermat little theorem: $x^{p} \equiv x \pmod{p}$ and if $x \neq 0$ then one can write this in the form $x^{p-1} \equiv 1 \pmod{p}$.

Comment: Thank you Antoine , and thank you Vincent, and thank you of course Hagen von Eitzen